# Can't delete from state synced to firebase - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem with deleting from the state that is synced to Firebase. I think the problem is coming from my delete function.

This is how I am syncing the state to the Firebase

```
componentDidMount() {
  base.syncState("recipes", {
    context: this,
    state: "recipes"
  });
   this.loadSampleData();
}
```

My delete function looks like this

```
deleteRecipe(index) {
   const recipes = { ...this.state.recipes };
   delete recipes[index];
   this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
 }
```

It worked without firebase but when I synced my state to firebase it stopped to work.

How to make it work with Firebase?

Comment: Maybe you want to call `syncState` after you have deleted a recipe as well?

Comment: @Tholle Why do I need to do this? When I edit recipe it gets edited in my firebase too without calling syncState in my edit function

Comment: I'm just speculating, I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Tholle btw I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my deleteRecipe function like that and it started to work:

```
deleteRecipe(index) {
   const recipes = { ...this.state.recipes };
   recipes[index] = null;
   this.setState({ recipes: recipes });
}
```